# Solution of linear equation obtained by partially differentiating a second degree general equation in two variables

Tags: analysis, partial-derivative, conic-sections, planar-graphs, proof-without-words

Let's consider a second degree equation in two variables say,
$$ S\equiv ax^2+by^2+2hxy+2gx+2fy+c=0 $$
where $a, b, c, f, g$ and $h$ are constants. To be clear, I'm dealing with conic sections here.

Depending on given data, the above equation can represent any of the following, namely

- pair of intersecting straight lines
- circle
- parabola
- ellipse
- hyperbola

Let's now consider the following two equations

$$L_1\equiv \frac{\partial S}{\partial x}=2ax+2hy+2g=0 \\
L_2\equiv \frac{\partial S}{\partial y}=2by+2hx+2f=0$$

It is widely known that if

**The equation represents pair of straight line:** The intersection of $L_1$ and $L_2$ give the point of intersection of the lines.

**The equation represents a circle:** The intersection of $L_1$ and $L_2$ give the centre of the circle.

**The equation represents a parabola:** The lines $L_1$ and $L_2$ give us an imaginary intersection. (Analogous with the argument that the parabola is a conic section whose center could be assumed to be taken at infinity).

**The equation represents a ellipse:** The intersection of $L_1$ and $L_2$ give the centre of the ellipse.

**The equation represents a hyperbola:** The intersection of $L_1$ and $L_2$ give the centre of the hyperbola.

But how were the above statements proven? Is there a way to graphically *visualise* what's going on? Why do these statements even make sense?

Comment: It's not the case for parabola.

Comment: @NgChungTak - Thanks for pointing out. I feel so dumb that I had my thoughts mixed up. I've edited it to correct the mistake.

Comment: @NgChungTak - Do you think partial derivatives could explain something if we consider the _3-D_ counterparts like ellipsoid, sphere or hyperboloid?

Comment: This trick doesn't work for cubic curves with center, so I think it cannot have a deep meaning. Anyway, it isn't difficult to prove it for a conic with center, if you want.

Comment: @IntelligentiPauca - what I mean to say is... Consider an ellipsoid $S'$ centred at origin . Consider a plane parallel to "$x-y$" say $z=z_0$. Impression of ellipsoid on that plane would give an ellipse considering an adequate range for $z_0$. Putting the $z_0$ in $S'$, we obtain an equation of ellipse say $S$. Again, intersection of $\frac{\partial S}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial S}{\partial y}$ would yield the centre of "impressed" ellipse. Similar would go for planes $x=x_0$ and $y=y_0$. There might me something we could get from here. Don't you think so?